# flow launched through a button inside the partner community

Tags: custom-button, visual-workflow, partner-communities

I built a flow to create a contract on an opportunity record. Then I put a button inside the opportunity page layout that launchs the flow. Now Our Partner community users can see the button , but when they use it an error occurs. How Can I make the flow available for partner community users?
Thank you for help me

Sorry now below you find the stamp of the error page:
[image]

when I try to assign the permission "RUN FLOW" to user with Partner Community License, the system throws the error "The user license doesn't allow the permission: Run Flows"

I did what Robin said, but the error is still the same. I created the vf page, embedded the flow interview and setted the security of the vf page.

Comment: What's the error ? Without adding error message it won't help anybody here to get you out of trouble

Comment: I'd expect them to need the flow user permission. Without it, they likely won't be able to run it. But as @MohithShrivastava asked, we need to know what the error message is to advise you.

Comment: Sorry I edit the post with the image of the error

Comment: Is the community Active or still in Preview?

Answer (score 1):

The Force.com Flow User feature license is not available for user with a Partner Community license. There is however a way to make it work for them as well:

1. [Embed the flow in a visualforce page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_advanced.htm)
2. As content source for your custom button, choose that visualforce page
3. Make sure you have made the visualforce page accessible for the profile you have given to your partner community user

Comment: This also works for Customer Community users.

Comment: I did what Robin said, but the error is still the same. I created the vf page, embedded the flow interview and setted the security of the vf page.

Comment: My guess is your finishLocation is not working correctly. Try putting <flow:interview name="Your_Flow" finishLocation="{!$Site.Prefix}/{!Opportunity.Id}"> in your visualforce page.

Answer (score 1):

if you are checking this issue in 2022, Partner communities now have access to flows. You can set a flow as an action on the custom Action button, and that will launch the flow, even for partner users.

Answer (score 0):

To complete what Robin said, do not forget to set your flow as active.
Go to your flow's detail page, and click "Activate" next to the version you prefer.